# Which SSDT version supports Oracle Database 12c?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to connect with Oracle 12c database using SSRS 2012. 
Getting the following error. I cannot change any property of Oracle db but can change the version of SSDT if required.

[image: Data source connection]

Answer (score 0):

A connection to an Oracle db requires Oracle Client software to be installed. It sounds like you do not have it installed or have a lower version.

> To use data from an Oracle database in your report, you must have a
>   dataset that's based on a report data source of type Oracle. This
>   built-in data source type uses the Oracle Data Provider directly and
>   requires an Oracle client software component.

[Oracle Connection Type (SSRS, Power BI Report Server, and Report Builder) - MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/oracle-connection-type-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15)

Check out the MS Docs for links are more information. Unfortunately, our OPs did this and haven't done this myself.